# Cython modules can be imported along with python package

Tags: python, package, cython

I made a python package with Cython components. When I import the package, I am able to import the Cython component directly. Is this normal?

For example,

```
import pkg1
import util  # Works for some reason
import foo  # Does not work
from pkg1 import foo  # Works as expected
```

works. How can I make it so you need the following to use `util`:

```
from pkg1 import util
```

Project Tree:

```
pkg1/
    setup.py
    pkg1/
        __init__.py
        util.pyx
        foo.py
        setup.py
```

I think there might be something wrong with my `pkg1/setup.py`

```
import setuptools
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

extensions = [
    Extension('pgk1.util', ['pkg1/util.c'])
]

setuptools.setup(
    # ...
    ext_modules=extensions,
    # ...
)
```

`pkg1/pkg1/setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension(name="util",
              sources=["util.pyx"])
]

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions, language_level="3")
)
```

Also, what is difference between `Extension` from `setuptools` and `distutils`?

This is my first Python package, so I am not exactly sure what everything does.

Comment: Your setup.py file doesn't look to be related to the file structure shown. [mre]

Comment: I guess the next questions would be: where does the .so file end up when you've run setup (are you doing "build_ext" or "install" and is it inplace)? How do you generate the .c file (may affect the name of the init function and so whether you can call from a package or now)?

Comment: I run `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace` while in pkg1/pkg1. The .so and .c files are in `pkg1/pkg1/`. Then in `pkg1/`, I run `python setup.py sdist` to generate the package.

Comment: To be honest I'm a little confused what's going on, but: you want one setup.py file and that should probably be the one in pkg1 (i.e. the outer directory). I could imagine that having two files that kind of overlap is confusing it

Comment: What should be in `pkg1/setup.py` then? I updated the post with `pkg1/pkg1/setup.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've been led into a mess by a typo which was meaning things weren't ending up where they should be:

```
Extension('pgk1.util', ...
```

should be `pkg1.util` - note that I've swapped two letters!

You only want one setup.py filo. It should be at the outermost level. In principle it can be responsible for building multiple packages (yours isn't). It takes care of all both the .pyx -> .c step and the .c -> .so step.

The following works:

```
import setuptools
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension('pkg1.util', ['pkg1/util.pyx'])
]

setuptools.setup(
    packages = setuptools.find_packages(),
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions, language_level=3),
    # ...
)
```

The changes are: I've fixed the pkg1/pgk1 type, I've added `cythonize` to the extensions, I've changed the source file to .pyx, and I've added `packages = setuptools.find_packages()`. This last change isn't needed if you're doing `build_ext --inplace` but does ensure that the .py files end up included if you use setup.py to install the package.

Delete your pkg1/pkg1/setup.py. It is not needed. Before you run this new one it's worth deleting the build directory and deleting the generated .c file(s) to ensure that everything gets rebuilt.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help!